# Strange buzzing sound coming from computer

Tags: desktop-computer, clicking-sound

My PC starts making a strange buzzing sound after being on for ~15 minutes, regardless of what is happening (no intense gaming or processing) and the CPU temp seems to remain normal.  I tried looking up coil whine but didn't seem to explain what I am hearing. I also used an aircan on the fans and that didn't seem to do anything.

The sound goes away immediately when the PC is turned off.  The noise seems to come from the top of the PC near the power switch.  Any idea what is causing this sound and how to fix it?

[Here is a video with audio](https://youtu.be/3BJMRTBnYF4)

Comment: Video is private, meaning general users cannot see it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This noise sounds like Coil Whine.

You may learn more about it and compare noises in the article
[What Is Coil Whine – What does it sound like – How To Fix It](https://www.cgdirector.com/fix-coil-whine/).
The article suggests some methods for dealing with the problem
(that you may not find to your taste).

As the problem arrives when powerful electrical fields interact,
it is usually to be found around the GPU and power supply.
If you manage to locate it exactly, perhaps you could introduce
(carefully) some isolation such as aluminum foil at this point to
separate the components.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  All the examples I had heard of coil whine sounded a bit more quiet than my case, plus I was hearing my sound more from the top of the PC near the power switch, and not the GPU.  Could that still be coil whine?

Comment: Coil Whine sound depends on the component that vibrates. I don't think there is just one sound for all.

Comment: Well, I left the machine on a bit and observed what caused it to trigger.  Apparently just bringing up Steam was enough, but I let it sit and the noise eventually went away.  I hope it stays that way!!!  I also appreciate your input!